# Generate entity related files based on current entity java class with jhipster

Tags: jhipster

Because of some reason, I want to use my current java entity classes to generate all entity related files, which are generated with `yo jhipster:entity book`. I need the liqibase configuration files, repository files, rest resources, and the sample files of html and js files.

So is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do that at the moment. But with JHipster 2 you could manually create a .jhipster/{entityname}.json file based on your class, and that would generate those files (and also recreate the class object) you're looking for.

Comment: ok, thanks. I checked some source code, also find that there is no such a way. So I created the json files manually.